# How to plot multiple columns of time data as line charts in R?

Tags: r, time

I have data that looks like the following sample:

```
Start Time:    
1. 2020-03-18 09:05:00
2. 2020-03-18 11:01:00
3. 2020-03-19 13:08:00

Response Time:
1. 2020-03-19 10:14:00
2. 2020-03-18 11:03:00
3. NA

End Time
1. 2020-04-23 20:13:00
2. 2020-04-01 16:21:00
3. 2020-04-01 17:06:00
```

As you can see, some values may be missing, but the event could still potentially have an end time. My goal is to plot the values as line charts from start to response to end. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are the values ?

Comment: I've only displayed three sample values in the question, but there are over 1000 in my dataset. I just want to visualize the mapping of time points from start to finish, with time on the x axis and maybe have the observations randomly dispersed on the y-axis.